# how to store multidimensional array value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an store which can be set directly as follows

```
self.xxx_bias_store[i][j] = [7,11]
```

where xxx can be different names

How do I set this using send. I have tried

```
self.send("#{name}_biases_store[#{i}][#{j}]=".to_sym, [7,11])
```

but this has no effect. Also interested in how to retrieve value i.e.

```
send("#{name}_biases_store[#{i}][#{j}]".to_sym)
```

Comment: why using `send` at all?

Comment: "Also interested in how to retrieve value i.e." => `bias_store[i][j]`?...

Comment: Because I have simplified the question, the name of the store can vary dynamically, so it looks more like ```self.send("#{name}_bias_store[#{i}][#{j}]=".to_sym, [7,11])```.  The retrieval looks like ```send("#{name}_bias_store[#{i}][#{j}]=".to_sym)```. But the #{name} part is not the problem.

Comment: Rather than dynamic variable names, you should consider making them hash keys. It will drastically simplify your code.

Comment: You are right and that is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you're trying to use send for this, and looking at your comment I'm not convinced you're actually asking the right question but regardless, here's how this works.

The methods you're concerned with look like this:

```
class Array
  def [](index)
    # Look up the element of the array at index
  end

  def []=(index, value)
    # Set the element of the array at index to value
  end
end
```

`thing[5]` calls the `[]` method with argument `5` - that is, it sends the method `[]` to the receiver `thing` with the argument `5`. Similarly, `thing[5]=1` calls the `[]=` method with arguments `5` and `1`

A multi-dimensional array is just an array made up of other arrays, so...

```
thing = [[1,2], [3,4]]
p thing.send(:[], 1) # => [3,4]
p thing.send(:[], 1).send(:[], 0) # => 3
thing.send(:[], 1).send(:[]=, 0, 5)
p thing # => [[1,2], [5,4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

> `send("biases_store[#{i}][#{j}]".to_sym)`

There's your error, thinking that `biases_store[i][j]` is one long complex method name. It's not. `biases_store` is a method, which returns something. And then you call method `[]` on that value which gets you yet another object. On which you call method `[]` again.

```
dynamic_property_name = 'biases_store'
send(dynamic_property_name)[i][j] = whatever
```

Or, same code rearranged for easier understanding

```
store = send('biases_store')
store[i][j] = whatever
```

Comment: It might be easier to do that in two lines: `store = send(name)` and `store[i][j] = value` (i.e. easier to understand)